# Property 'confidence' does not exist on type '{ label: string; confidence: string; } | undefined'

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint

When I try to destructure the return type of the following function:

```
const coreml = async (
  pathToImage: string,
): Promise<{label: string; confidence: string} | undefined> => {
  //body
};
```

as such:

```
const {label, confidence} = await coreml(/*path to image*/);
```

I get

```
'confidence' is assigned a value but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
Property 'confidence' does not exist on type '{ label: string; confidence: string; } | undefined'.
```

Comment: If the promise resolves to `undefined`, what value will `confidence` have?

Comment: I think I would wrap this within a trycatch block, to avoid that.

Comment: But as [derprisher's answer mentions, TypeScript runs at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68446188/215552), before try/catches enter into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of your function is either `{label: string, confidence: string}` or `undefined`. Which one is unknown at compile time. But you cannot deconstruct `undefined` into `label`  and `confidence` and typescript wants to ensure type safety. Thus the error.

In principle the deconstruction works as follows:

```
const temp = await coreml();
//temp is now either {"label": "foo", "confidence": "bar"}  or undefined

//but the next statements will throw an error, if temp is undefined
const label = temp.label;
const confidence = temp.confidence;
```

Typescript wants to ensure, this error doesn't happen at runtime. Thus, the error at compile time

Comment: Would this work?

```try {const {label, confidence} = await coreml(routeParams.uri)} catch (error){console.log(error)}```

Comment: Not in TypeScript, which is compile-time, not runtime.

Comment: Are you sure that wouldn't work? Because I believe I've done something similar inside of a React component's useEffect() hook. I ran a self-calling async function upon component mount. I don't know if you have React experience, but would you say that might make the matter different?

Comment: ```React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const {promise} = await RNFS.downloadFile(/*this will return a Promise obj*/);
        console.log('promise', (await promise).statusCode);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(
          error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);```

Comment: I apologize for how messy that looks. I don't know if it's better or worse I remove the tabs. And for some clarity the function being 'awaited' will return a Promise containing a *promise* member of type obj.

Comment: `RNFS.downloadfile` always returns `{ jobId: number, promise: Promise<DownloadResult> }`and never `undefined`. Thus the deconstruction is always possible.